# Galleria Galleries Not Loading Correctly After Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll, galleria

I have a website built on WordPress with a couple of hundred posts. Each post contains up to 10 images. Infinite Scroll is used to load in more posts automatically. What I want is for the main page to be a page of image galleries; one per post.

Here is what I have:

First, I add the galleries in the post loop. I use the post ID to create a unique Galleria ID. I also use a second class name to pass the image ratio to the JS (sure there is a better way?):

```
<div id="galleria-1609" class="galleria 0.5">
    <a href="img01-800x400.jpg" alt="Large Image" ><img src="thumb.png" /></a>
    <a href="img02-800x400.jpg" alt="Large Image" ><img src="thumb.png" /></a>
</div>
```

...and then the javascript is added...

```
<script>
    Galleria.run('#galleria-1609', {
        thumbnails: 'numbers',
        height: 0.5, /* ratio */
        preload: 1
    });
</script>
```

This works fine for the first set of Galleries but when infinite scroll loads more posts, the javascript is stripped. After some searching I found Infinite Scroll has a callback function with access to the Array of new elements.

So  I tried this code in a function called from the infinite scroll callback:

```
function loadSliders(arrayOfNewElems) {
    $(arrayOfNewElems).each(function( i ) {
        var newGal = $(this).find('.galleria');
        //extract ratio from 2nd class name:
        var ratio = $(newGal).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        var thisID = '#'+ $(newGal).attr('id');

       Galleria.run(thisID, {
            thumbnails: 'numbers',
            height: ratio,
            preload: 1
        });
    });
}
```

This does load one more set of Galleries, but fails after with this error:

`TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined`

Any ideas on why I am getting this error or better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it worked out. For anyone else stuck on a similar problem. This is what I ended up with:

HTML:

```
<div id="galleria-1609" class="galleria" data-ratio="0.5">
    <a href="img01-800x400.jpg" alt="Large Image" ><img src="thumb.png" /></a>
    <a href="img02-800x400.jpg" alt="Large Image" ><img src="thumb.png" /></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function loadSliders(arrayOfNewElems) {
    $(arrayOfNewElems).each(function( i ) {
        $(this).find('.galleria').each(function( j ) {
            //var ratio = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
            //improved method:
            var ratio = $(this).data('ratio');
            var thisID = '#'+ $(this).attr('id');       
            Galleria.run(thisID, {
                    thumbnails: 'numbers',
                    height: ratio,
                    preload: 1
                });
        });
    });
}
```

Updated to show HTML5 data- attribute as described in my comment.

Comment: Found a better way... Using [HTML5's data- attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) I created an attribute called `data-ratio` on the Galleria div and grab it in the JS above using `var ratio = $(this).data('ratio');`.